# Linker error undefined symbols for arm64 symengine

Tags: c++11, linker, symengine

I'm trying to work with symengine on my Mac, however there is a persistent linking error I'm unable to solve. I installed symengine the "default" way with `condo install symengine`. I'm trying to compile the following minimal example `random.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <symengine/expression.h>

using SymEngine::Expression;


int main() {
    Expression e("e");
    std::cout << "Defined Expression: " << e << "\n";
    return 0;
};
```

with `clang++ -std=c++11 -I/path/to/symengine/include random.cpp`. However, I get the following error telling me that `ld` is unable to find symbols for my arm64 architecture:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "SymEngine::Expression::Expression(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      _main in random-79496f.o
  "SymEngine::Basic::__str__() const", referenced from:
      SymEngine::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, SymEngine::Expression const&) in random-79496f.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

After a google search I tried to compile with `-stdlib=libc++`, but the error persists. -v gives the following additional output:

```
"/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -no_deduplicate -dynamic -arch arm64 -platform_version macos 13.0.0 13.1 -syslibroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -o a.out -L/usr/local/lib /var/folders/58/n0sq8txx0bn1cz6w6kxzyh500000gn/T/random-79496f.o -lc++ -lSystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
```

For me it seems that the linker cannot find the right library, but I'm not quite sure what the error message tells me. Any help is very much appreciated!